# show CSV file content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, csv

I need to display CSV file content in iOS app(for ipad mini) in grid.
Some thing like this:
[image]

What library/control can I use to make this more easy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just display or also edit?

Comment: The problem is? Reading the CSV file or displaying a dynamic table? If you need the combination you probably need an office application. If the problem is just one part, please clarify your question

Comment: just for display, and row selection.

Comment: For displaying you can use QLPreviewController. Supports CSV files

Comment: What about this: http://www.netwalk.be/article/quicklook-for-the-win
any ideas? is this good solution?

Comment: @IAmDav Thats the controller I suggested.

Comment: What the reasons for down votes?

Comment: @Aris thanks, I will have a look on it.

Comment: @FahimParkar,This is technical question, not human resource

Comment: @IAmDav This sort of question is explicitly barred in the FAQ.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, sorry, but I can't find good library to use. google dont help, that why I asked it, there is also no(at least I dont find) any SO question for this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use MMSPreadsheetView

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMSpreadsheetView

It uses collectionView which will make your cell selection easy.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this and QLPreviewController is what I was looking for.